# Table Height different between Ipad and Laptop (using html <iframe>

Tags: html, ipad

I create a website by using [wix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wix.com). To put tables on my website, I used the html widget. 
However, there is height limit on the html widget, so I have to split some of my tables into 2 parts. The problem is the height of my tables change between ipad and laptop, it turns out that text overlapped between tables on the ipad. To avoid text overlapping, I have to leave big gap between tables on my laptop. Does anyone know how to solve it?

The pictures below are the screenshots of my ipad and laptop.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39965960/2013-11-16%2004.12.01.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39965960/abnormal.png

The html code of my table width and my  code are as below

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
                body,td,th {
                    font-family: Verdana, Verdana, Verdana;
                    font-size: 12px;
                }
                </STYLE>
                <table width=900 border="1" cellspacing="0" style='table-layout:fixed'>
                <col width="11%">
                <col width="11%">
                <col width="33%">
                <col width="16%">
                <col width="16%">
                <col width="6%">
                <col width="7%">
                <col width="7%">

                <tr bgcolor="#00aaaa">
```

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

        body,
        html {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <iframe src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B5mkUGmS3zi7T1hiRTZ2OEVTb0U/Edu_iframe_1_1.html" scrolling="no"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you created website using wix? I am lost, what is wix?

Comment: I think he's talking about the Wix web development platform (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wix.com)

Comment: Wix is a horrible flash based website creator